# how to restrict access specific article in joomla by IP address?

Tags: joomla

i have one article under a menu in JOOMLA and want to restrict the contents of that article by range of allowed or deny IP addresses. please suggest.

Comment: My suggestion is to add more detail in your question, be specific and add a code example.

Comment: @gomzi If you are doing Joomla development work, I might recommend that you join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and post your Joomla-specific questions there.  That said, Your question is missing a lot of expected details.  You haven't provided any context or reason to do what you want to do.  We don't know what you tried so far nor what research you have conducted.  If you post on JSE, I hope you will be far more generous with your question details.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this one is customizing source code inside com_content component if you are a developer

```
<?php $deny = array("111.111.111", "222.222.222", "333.333.333");
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
   header("location: https://example.com/");
   exit();
} ?>
```

Comment: So the OP should just hack the Joomla source code and avoid upgrading to newer versions of the CMS?

Comment: Actually i have one article under a menu and want to restrict the contents of that article by range of allowed or deny IP address. i am not a developer but i can do if i am guided properly. hope you are talking about content file available under \htdocs\joomla\components\com_content ??